# Entity Framework 2.0 Creates Only First Auto Table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework to save the information. I have a context and I have two datasets

```
    public class AplicacaoContexto : DbContext
    {
        public AplicacaoContexto(DbContextOptions<AplicacaoContexto> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TipoConteudo> TiposConteudo { get; set; }
    }
```

My Configure Services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration["ConexaoMySql:MySqlConnectionString"];

            services.AddDbContext<AplicacaoContexto>(options =>
               options.UseMySql(connection)
           );


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

I am creating the web project web api, and creating 2 controllers to Empresa and the other for the TipoConteudo.

When I send a request to the Empresa, he can create the table and save the information.

But when I do the same action on the TipoConteudo, however, it returns me the following error:

```
MySqlException: Table 'dbplatformcourses.tipoconteudo' doesn't exist
```

Why does it happen? how can i create the table?

Controller

```
 public class TipoConteudoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AplicacaoContexto _context;

        public TipoConteudoController(AplicacaoContexto context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

... methods http
}
```

[EDIT]

I was able to create the tables using the _context.Database.EnsureCreated () command; however I do not know where is the correct place to use this statement. I added it inside my controller, where can I call this instruction? since in my startup.cs I don't have access to my context.

Comment: Your DbSet name is `TiposConteudo`, but the error refers to `tipcontent`. Please edit your question to show where you are sending a request to `TiposConteudo`

Comment: my dbset is TiposConteudo and my table is TipoConteudo, as it is in the class.
The call I make is automatically generated on the controller. I added in the question, please look.

Comment: if you write mapping for entities please share that, if not share the entity classes

Comment: I edited the question I managed to create but I don't know where I should call the command